# Character spacing increases when going to next line in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I've got a text view whose text alignment is set to .justified. Take a look at this GIF:

[image: .justified alignment problem in text views]

Notice how the character spacing increased when I went to the next line, that is (I think) because the text view's alignment is set to .justified and so the text in the particular line is spacing out to fill the entire line.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

> (I think) because the text view's alignment is set to .justified and
>   so the text in the particular line is spacing out to fill the entire
>   line.

You just answered your own question. This is the default behavior of `justified`. Also you are adding a word that is too long, and it's not even a word anyways, meaning if you type some phrases with real words (by real words I mean words that do exist in a dictionary), you will see that there's really nothing wrong in your textView.

To explain how `justified` works:

> *Justified text* is spaced so the left and right sides of the text block
>   both have a clean edge. The usual alternative to justified text is
>   *left-aligned text*, which has a straight left edge and an uneven right
>   edge. Compared to left-aligned text, justification gives text a
>   cleaner, more formal look.
>
> Justification works by adding white space between the words in each
>   line so all the lines are the same length. This alters the ideal
>   spacing of the font, but in paragraphs of reasonable width it’s
>   usually not distracting.

Reference: https://practicaltypography.com/justified-text.html

Comment: "meaning if you type some phrases with real words" I did, that's how I noticed this problem in the first place.